# Cypher Query returning value

Tags: cypher

Is it possible to type cast like

```
start n=node(0) match n-[:My_Events]->m where 
    has(m.Node_Type) and has(m.Day1) and 
    m.Node_Type='Schdule_Node' and 
    m.Day1<>'' 
       return id(m) ORDER BY Integer.parseInt(m.Day1) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

toInt appears to work on http://console.neo4j.org

```
start n=node(0) match n-[:My_Events]->m
where 
    has(m.Node_Type) and has(m.Day1) and 
    m.Node_Type='Schdule_Node' and 
    m.Day1<>'' 
return id(m) ORDER BY toInt(m.Day1)
```

Comment: It should work in Cypher 2.0.2 https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/packaging/standalone/standalone-enterprise/src/main/distribution/text/enterprise/CHANGES.txt